# How do I check if 2 numbers are equal to a specific ratio in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example: I want to know wether 5 and 500 have a 1:100 ratio, I also want to know how I can see if they ***roughly*** have the same ratio or not, how do I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know whether `a/b` and `c/d` are roughly the same ratio, then (in Python 3 only) you can do `math.abs(a/b - c/d) < margin`. The smaller the positive number `margin` is, the more close the ratios have to be for the expression to return `True`. `margin = 1/100` would be within a percentage point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#module-fractions) module for precise comparison:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction

>>> Fraction('5/500') == Fraction('1/100')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check that the difference between cross product is less than the higher of the two denominators:

```
def sameRatio(a,b,c,d): return abs(a*d-b*c)<max(b,d)
```

output:

```
>>> sameRatio(5,500,1,100)     # True
>>> sameRatio(9,500,1,100)     # True
>>> sameRatio(9,500,2,100)     # True
>>> sameRatio(10,500,1,100)    # False
>>> sameRatio(10,500,2,100)    # True
>>> sameRatio(1,500,1,100)     # True
>>> sameRatio(0,500,1,100)     # False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also leverage the `as_integer_ratio` method of `float`s.

```py
x = 5/500
y = 1/100
x.as_integer_ratio() == y.as_integer_ratio()
```